# jquery onblur not firing

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to get an onblur/onfocus combination working for a pair of text boxes which I am selecting via class in jquery. I am not getting any errors in debug, but the blur function never seems to be called. When debugging my breakpoint in the blur function is not hit.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var row = $(this).closest('tr');
    $('.editClass').click(function () {
        var editBoxes = $(row).find('.editClass');
        var focus = 0;
        $(editBoxes).focus(function () { focus++ });
        $(editBoxes).blur(function () {
            focus--;
            setTimeout(function () {
                if (!focus) {
                    alert('LOST FOCUS'); // both lost focus
                }
            }, 50);
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: can you please provide information clearly

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pretty sure the problem here was that the editBoxes were dynamically added to the page. This was not apparent in my question. Since they were dyncamically added I need to use

```
$(document).on('blur', '.editBoxes', function (){
 ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The last two lines of your code example should be this

```
    });
});
```

This is needed for closing the ready and click function call.

Another possible problem is that you wrap the focus and blur listeners in a click handlers. Why did you do this?

Comment: Thanks the missing brackets and parenthesis were just typos from me copy/pasting my code. I am attempting to bind the handlers dynamically when the '.editClass' is clicked, so that is why it is wrapped in the click handler.